# "men's shavers" vs. "shavers for men"

Tags: word-usage

Googling "men's shavers" gives results that look like this

[image]

Which contain both phrases like "men's shavers" and "shavers for men", do they mean the same thing? If yes, why doesn't Ngram Viewer even have the latter?

[image]

Comment: [returns results, not gives results] we just say: electric shavers for men, electric shavers for women. men's shavers is not the formal term.

Comment: @Lambie Your correction is very helpful, thank you. Assume I'm in a store, would I say "I'd like to a men's shaver"? Because it's an informal setting, right?

Comment: Yes. Actually, it's a question of emphasis. Consider: "I'd like to look at shavers." "Yes, sir, I assume you mean shavers *for men*". Compare with "Where is the men's section. I need underwear and *men's* shavers". In both cases, the last word adds the new information. I think that advertisers prefer "shavers for men", because when a man hears "for men", he may feel an important connection. But the meaning of both is the same..

Comment: You may say what you like, but in a drugstore, you'd probably use the plural:men's shavers, as a product section. Bear in mind, there are also men's razors, men's electric razors.